# Eh Cache expiry time in Spring boot

Tags: java, ehcache

I have created a spring boot application and implemented EhCache in the maven project. My xml configuration file for EhCache is as follows :

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" 
dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

<cache name="labCabSourceInfoCache" 
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
    maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
    eternal="false" 
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="300"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
    transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

I have set expiry time as 300 in the parameters timeToIdleSeconds & timeToLiveSeconds

But it doesn't works for me. I didn't used any configuration bean for the cache implementaion. I uses @Cacheable annotation for the method which is meant to be used cache.

```
@Cacheable(value="labCabSourceInfoCache", key="#labAlias.concat(#Account)") 
public String findLabCabSourceInfo(String labAlias, String Account) { 
    try { 
        //codes return "some string" 
    } catch (Exception e) { } return null; 
}
```

Why it is not evicted or cleared?

Comment: can you please post one of your methods with the @Cacheable Annotation?

Comment: Can you see my code now?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what does not "work"? Also eviction happens when capacity limits are reached, cleared would require an explicit remove. The terminology is "expires" and I wonder how you asses it to be working or not.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the processing of the caching annotations.
Can you try adding @EnableCaching on your main class.

From the tutorial 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/

> The @EnableCaching annotation triggers a post processor that inspects
>   every Spring bean for the presence of caching annotations on public
>   methods. If such an annotation is found, a proxy is automatically
>   created to intercept the method call and handle the caching behavior
>   accordingly.

Also you can add the following code in and then analyse thorough Jconsole, the details of the caches created in your application.

```
@Bean(initMethod="init")
@Autowired
public ManagementService managementService(CacheManager cacheManager,
              MBeanServer mBeanServer) {
       return new ManagementService(cacheManager, mBeanServer, true, true,true, true);
}
```